# Functions not recognized when using Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, jquery-validate, gulp-watch, gulp-concat

I just switched from codekit (a program that minifies / concats / renders sass and js files) to the Gulp build system. I have created a gulpfile and it seems that everything is concatenating and uglifying just fine, but when i try to use a function, like "validate()" for instance, it doesn't work. But that function is clearly defined towards the top of the minified document and called at the very end of the document. Any ideas why all the functions in the top of the file are not working? Headroom(), equalHeights(), validate(), none of those are working.

My gulpfile.js

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
var order = require("gulp-order");
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var refresh = require('gulp-livereload');
var lr = require('tiny-lr');
var server = lr();
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var embedlr = require('gulp-embedlr');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
        gulp.src([
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/*.js",
          "public/assets/js/partials/*.js"
        ])
        .pipe(order([
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/jquery.js",
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/modernizr.min.js",
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/bootstrap.js",
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/equalheights.js",
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/headroom.js",
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/jquery.headroom.js",
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/jquery.maskedinput.min.js",
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/jquery.validate.js",
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/plupload.full.min.js",
          "public/assets/js/frameworks/wow.js",
          "public/assets/js/partials/*.js"
        ], { base: './' }))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/dist'))
        .pipe(refresh(server))
})

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src(['public/assets/scss/**/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/dist'))
        .pipe(refresh(server))
})

gulp.task('lr-server', function() {
    server.listen(35729, function(err) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
    });
})


gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.run('lr-server', 'scripts', 'styles');

    gulp.watch('public/assets/js/**/*.js', function(event) {
        gulp.run('scripts');
    })

    gulp.watch('public/assets/scss/**/*.scss', function(event) {
        gulp.run('styles');
    })
})
```

My minified file is too long to post, but the validate() function is defined as follows and its towards the top of the file:

```
{validate:function(t){if(!this.length)return void(t&&t.debug&&window.console&&console.warn("Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing."));var n=e.data(this[0],"validator");return n?n:(this.attr("novalidate","novalidate"),n=new e.validator(t,this[0]),e.data(this[0],"validator",n),n.settings.onsubmit&&(this.on("click.validate",":submit",function(t){n.settings.submitHandler&&(n.submitButton=t.target),e(this).hasClass("cancel")&&(n.cancelSubmit=!0),void 0!==e(this).attr("formnovalidate")&&(n.cancelSubmit=!0)}),this.on("submit.validate",function(t){function i(){var i,r;return!n.settings.submitHandler||(n.submitButton&&(i=e("<input type='hidden'/>").attr("name",n.submitButton.name).val(e(n.submitButton).val()).appendTo(n.currentForm)),r=n.settings.submitHandler.call(n,n.currentForm,t),n.submitButton&&i.remove(),void 0!==r&&r)}return n.settings.debug&&t.preventDefault(),n.cancelSubmit?(n.cancelSubmit=!1,i()):n.form()?n.pendingRequest?(n.formSubmitted=!0,!1):i():(n.focusInvalid(),!1)})),n)},valid:function(){var t,n,i;return e(this[0]).is("form")?t=this.validate().form():(i=[],t=!0,n=e(this[0].form).validate(),this.each(function(){t=n.element(this)&&t,t||(i=i.concat(n.errorList))}),n.errorList=i),t},rules:function(t,n){if(this.length){var i,r,o,s,a,l,u=this[0];if(t)switch(i=e.data(u.form,"validator").settings,r=i.rules,o=e.validator.staticRules(u),t){case"add":e.extend(o,e.validator.normalizeRule(n)),delete o.messages,r[u.name]=o,n.messages&&(i.messages[u.name]=e.extend(i.messages[u.name],n.messages));break;case"remove":return n?(l={},e.each(n.split(/\s/),function(t,n){l[n]=o[n],delete o[n],"required"===n&&e(u).removeAttr("aria-required")}),l):(delete r[u.name],o)}return s=e.validator.normalizeRules(e.extend({},e.validator.classRules(u),e.validator.attributeRules(u),e.validator.dataRules(u),e.validator.staticRules(u)),u),s.required&&(a=s.required,delete s.required,s=e.extend({required:a},s),e(u).attr("aria-required","true")),s.remote&&(a=s.remote,delete s.remote,s=e.extend(s,{remote:a})),s}}}),e.extend(e.expr[":"],{blank:function(t){return!e.trim(""+e(t).val())},filled:function(t){var n=e(t).val();return null!==n&&!!e.trim(""+n)},unchecked:function(t){return!e(t).prop("checked")}}),e.validator=function(t,n){this.settings=e.extend(!0,{},e.validator.defaults,t),this.currentForm=n,this.init()},e.validator.format=function(t,n){return 1===arguments.length?function(){var n=e.makeArray(arguments);return n.unshift(t),e.validator.format.apply(this,n)}:void 0===n?t:(arguments.length>2&&n.constructor!==Array&&(n=e.makeArray(arguments).slice(1)),n.constructor!==Array&&(n=[n]),e.each(n,function(e,n){t=t.replace(new RegExp("\\{"+e+"\\}","g"),function(){return n})}),t)},e.extend(e.validator,{defaults:{messages:{},groups:{},rules:{},errorClass:"error",pendingClass:"pending",validClass:"valid",errorElement:"label",focusCleanup:!1,focusInvalid:!0,errorContainer:e([]),errorLabelContainer:e([]),onsubmit:!0,ignore:":hidden",ignoreTitle:!1,onfocusin:function(e){this.lastActive=e,this.settings.focusCleanup&&(this.settings.unhighlight&&this.settings.unhighlight.call(this,e,this.settings.errorClass,this.settings.validClass),this.hideThese(this.errorsFor(e)))},onfocusout:function(e){this.checkable(e)||!(e.name in this.submitted)&&this.optional(e)||this.element(e)},onkeyup:function(t,n){var i=[16,17,18,20,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,144,225];9===n.which&&""===this.elementValue(t)||e.inArray(n.keyCode,i)!==-1||(t.name in this.submitted||t.name in this.invalid)&&this.element(t)},onclick:function(e){e.name in this.submitted?this.element(e):e.parentNode.name in this.submitted&&this.element(e.parentNode)},highlight:function(t,n,i){"radio"===t.type?this.findByName(t.name).addClass(n).removeClass(i):e(t).addClass(n).removeClass(i)},unhighlight:function(t,n,i){"radio"===t.type?this.findByName(t.name).removeClass(n).addClass(i):e(t).removeClass(n).addClass(i)}},setDefaults:function(t){e.extend(e.validator.defaults,t)},messages:{required:"This field is required.",remote:"Please fix this field.",email:"Please enter a valid email address.",url:"Please enter a valid URL.",date:"Please enter a valid date.",dateISO:"Please enter a valid date ( ISO ).",number:"Please enter a valid number.",digits:"Please enter only digits.",equalTo:"Please enter the same value again.",maxlength:e.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),minlength:e.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),rangelength:e.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),range:e.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),max:e.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),min:e.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}."),step:e.validator.format("Please enter a multiple of {0}.")},autoCreateRanges:!1,prototype:{init:function(){function t(t){var n=e.data(this.form,"validator"),i="on"+t.type.replace(/^validate/,""),r=n.settings;r[i]&&!e(this).is(r.ignore)&&r[i].call(n,this,t)}this.labelContainer=e(this.settings.errorLabelContainer),this.errorContext=this.labelContainer.length&&this.labelContainer||e(this.currentForm),this.containers=e(this.settings.errorContainer).add(this.settings.errorLabelContainer),this.submitted={},this.valueCache={},this.pendingRequest=0,this.pending={},this.invalid={},this.reset();var n,i=this.groups={};e.each(this.settings.groups,function(t,n){"string"==typeof n&&(n=n.split(/\s/)),e.each(n,function(e,n){i[n]=t})}),n=this.settings.rules,e.each(n,function(t,i){n[t]=e.validator.normalizeRule(i)}),e(this.currentForm).on("focusin.validate focusout.validate keyup.validate",":text, [type='password'], [type='file'], select, textarea, [type='number'], [type='search'], [type='tel'], [type='url'], [type='email'], [type='datetime'], [type='date'], [type='month'], [type='week'], [type='time'], [type='datetime-local'], [type='range'], [type='color'], [type='radio'], [type='checkbox'], [contenteditable]",t).on("click.validate","select, option, [type='radio'], [type='checkbox']",t),this.settings.invalidHandler&&e(this.currentForm).on("invalid-form.validate",this.settings.invalidHandler),e(this.currentForm).find("[required], [data-rule-required], .required").attr("aria-required","true")},form:function(){return this.checkForm(),e.extend(this.submitted,this.errorMap),this.invalid=e.extend({},this.errorMap),this.valid()||e(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form",[this]),this.showErrors(),this.valid()},checkForm:function(){this.prepareForm();for(var e=0,t=this.currentElements=this.elements();t[e];e++)this.check(t[e]);return this.valid()},element:function(t){var n,i,r=this.clean(t),o=this.validationTargetFor(r),s=this,a=!0;return void 0===o?delete this.invalid[r.name]:(this.prepareElement(o),this.currentElements=e(o),i=this.groups[o.name],i&&e.each(this.groups,function(e,t){t===i&&e!==o.name&&(r=s.validationTargetFor(s.clean(s.findByName(e))),r&&r.name in s.invalid&&(s.currentElements.push(r),a=a&&s.check(r)))}),n=this.check(o)!==!1,a=a&&n,n?this.invalid[o.name]=!1:this.invalid[o.name]=!0,this.numberOfInvalids()||(this.toHide=this.toHide.add(this.containers)),this.showErrors(),e(t).attr("aria-invalid",!n)),a},showErrors:function(t){if(t){var n=this;e.extend(this.errorMap,t),this.errorList=e.map(this.errorMap,function(e,t){return{message:e,element:n.findByName(t)[0]}}),this.successList=e.grep(this.successList,function(e){return!(e.name in t)})}this.settings.showErrors?this.settings.showErrors.call(this,this.errorMap,this.errorList):this.defaultShowErrors()},resetForm:function(){e.fn.resetForm&&e(this.currentForm).resetForm(),this.invalid={},this.submitted={},this.prepareForm(),this.hideErrors();var t=this.elements().removeData("previousValue").removeAttr("aria-invalid");this.resetElements(t)},resetElements:function(e){var t;if(this.settings.unhighlight)for(t=0;e[t];t++)this.settings.unhighlight.call(this,e[t],this.settings.errorClass,""),this.findByName(e[t].name).removeClass(this.settings.validClass);else e.removeClass(this.settings.errorClass).removeClass(this.settings.validClass)},numberOfInvalids:function(){return this.objectLength(this.invalid)},objectLength:function(e){var t,n=0;for(t in e)e[t]&&n++;return n},hideErrors:function(){this.hideThese(this.toHide)},hideThese:function(e){e.not(this.containers).text(""),this.addWrapper(e).hide()},valid:function(){return 0===this.size()},size:function(){return this.errorList.length},focusInvalid:function(){if(this.settings.focusInvalid)try{e(this.findLastActive()||this.errorList.length&&this.errorList[0].element||[]).filter(":visible").focus().trigger("focusin")}catch(e){}},findLastActive:function(){var t=this.lastActive;return t&&1===e.grep(this.errorList,function(e){return e.element.name===t.name}).length&&t},elements:function(){var t=this,n={};return e(this.currentForm).find("input, select, textarea, [contenteditable]").not(":submit, :reset, :image, :disabled").not(this.settings.ignore).filter(function(){var i=this.name||e(this).attr("name");return!i&&t.settings.debug&&window.console&&console.error("%o has no name assigned",this),this.hasAttribute("contenteditable")&&(this.form=e(this).closest("form")[0]),!(i in n||!t.objectLength(e(this).rules()))&&(n[i]=!0,!0)})},clean:function(t){return e(t)[0]},errors:function(){var t=this.settings.errorClass.split(" ").join(".");return e(this.settings.errorElement+"."+t,this.errorContext)},resetInternals:function(){this.successList=[],this.errorList=[],this.errorMap={},this.toShow=e([]),this.toHide=e([])},reset:function(){this.resetInternals(),this.currentElements=e([])},prepareForm:function(){this.reset(),this.toHide=this.errors().add(this.containers)},prepareElement:function(e){
this.reset(),this.toHide=this.errorsFor(e)},elementValue:function(t){var n,i,r=e(t),o=t.type;return"radio"===o||"checkbox"===o?this.findByName(t.name).filter(":checked").val():"number"===o&&"undefined"!=typeof t.validity?t.validity.badInput?"NaN":r.val():(n=t.hasAttribute("contenteditable")?r.text():r.val(),"file"===o?"C:\\fakepath\\"===n.substr(0,12)?n.substr(12):(i=n.lastIndexOf("/"),i>=0?n.substr(i+1):(i=n.lastIndexOf("\\"),i>=0?n.substr(i+1):n)):"string"==typeof n?n.replace(/\r/g,""):n)},check:function(t){t=this.validationTargetFor(this.clean(t));var n,i,r,o=e(t).rules(),s=e.map(o,function(e,t){return t}).length,a=!1,l=this.elementValue(t);if("function"==typeof o.normalizer){if(l=o.normalizer.call(t,l),"string"!=typeof l)throw new TypeError("The normalizer should return a string value.");delete o.normalizer}for(i in o){r={method:i,parameters:o[i]};try{if(n=e.validator.methods[i].call(this,l,t,r.parameters),"dependency-mismatch"===n&&1===s){a=!0;continue}if(a=!1,"pending"===n)return void(this.toHide=this.toHide.not(this.errorsFor(t)));if(!n)return this.formatAndAdd(t,r),!1}catch(e){throw this.settings.debug&&window.console&&console.log("Exception occurred when checking element "+t.id+", check the '"+r.method+"' method.",e),e instanceof TypeError&&(e.message+=".  Exception occurred when checking element "+t.id+", check the '"+r.method+"' method."),e}}if(!a)return this.objectLength(o)&&this.successList.push(t),!0},customDataMessage:function(t,n){return e(t).data("msg"+n.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+n.substring(1).toLowerCase())||e(t).data("msg")},customMessage:function(e,t){var n=this.settings.messages[e];return n&&(n.constructor===String?n:n[t])},findDefined:function(){for(var e=0;e<arguments.length;e++)if(void 0!==arguments[e])return arguments[e]},defaultMessage:function(t,n){var i=this.findDefined(this.customMessage(t.name,n.method),this.customDataMessage(t,n.method),!this.settings.ignoreTitle&&t.title||void 0,e.validator.messages[n.method],"<strong>Warning: No message defined for "+t.name+"</strong>"),r=/\$?\{(\d+)\}/g;return"function"==typeof i?i=i.call(this,n.parameters,t):r.test(i)&&(i=e.validator.format(i.replace(r,"{$1}"),n.parameters)),i},formatAndAdd:function(e,t){var n=this.defaultMessage(e,t);this.errorList.push({message:n,element:e,method:t.method}),this.errorMap[e.name]=n,this.submitted[e.name]=n},addWrapper:function(e){return this.settings.wrapper&&(e=e.add(e.parent(this.settings.wrapper))),e},defaultShowErrors:function(){var e,t,n;for(e=0;this.errorList[e];e++)n=this.errorList[e],this.settings.highlight&&this.settings.highlight.call(this,n.element,this.settings.errorClass,this.settings.validClass),this.showLabel(n.element,n.message);if(this.errorList.length&&(this.toShow=this.toShow.add(this.containers)),this.settings.success)for(e=0;this.successList[e];e++)this.showLabel(this.successList[e]);if(this.settings.unhighlight)for(e=0,t=this.validElements();t[e];e++)this.settings.unhighlight.call(this,t[e],this.settings.errorClass,this.settings.validClass);this.toHide=this.toHide.not(this.toShow),this.hideErrors(),this.addWrapper(this.toShow).show()},validElements:function(){return this.currentElements.not(this.invalidElements())},invalidElements:function(){return e(this.errorList).map(function(){return this.element})},showLabel:function(t,n){var i,r,o,s,a=this.errorsFor(t),l=this.idOrName(t),u=e(t).attr("aria-describedby");a.length?(a.removeClass(this.settings.validClass).addClass(this.settings.errorClass),a.html(n)):(a=e("<"+this.settings.errorElement+">").attr("id",l+"-error").addClass(this.settings.errorClass).html(n||""),i=a,this.settings.wrapper&&(i=a.hide().show().wrap("<"+this.settings.wrapper+"/>").parent()),this.labelContainer.length?this.labelContainer.append(i):this.settings.errorPlacement?this.settings.errorPlacement(i,e(t)):i.insertAfter(t),a.is("label")?a.attr("for",l):0===a.parents("label[for='"+this.escapeCssMeta(l)+"']").length&&(o=a.attr("id"),u?u.match(new RegExp("\\b"+this.escapeCssMeta(o)+"\\b"))||(u+=" "+o):u=o,e(t).attr("aria-describedby",u),r=this.groups[t.name],r&&(s=this,e.each(s.groups,function(t,n){n===r&&e("[name='"+s.escapeCssMeta(t)+"']",s.currentForm).attr("aria-describedby",a.attr("id"))})))),!n&&this.settings.success&&(a.text(""),"string"==typeof this.settings.success?a.addClass(this.settings.success):this.settings.success(a,t)),this.toShow=this.toShow.add(a)},errorsFor:function(t){var n=this.escapeCssMeta(this.idOrName(t)),i=e(t).attr("aria-describedby"),r="label[for='"+n+"'], label[for='"+n+"'] *";return i&&(r=r+", #"+this.escapeCssMeta(i).replace(/\s+/g,", #")),this.errors().filter(r)},escapeCssMeta:function(e){return e.replace(/([\\!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^`{|}~])/g,"\\$1")},idOrName:function(e){return this.groups[e.name]||(this.checkable(e)?e.name:e.id||e.name)},validationTargetFor:function(t){return this.checkable(t)&&(t=this.findByName(t.name)),e(t).not(this.settings.ignore)[0]},checkable:function(e){return/radio|checkbox/i.test(e.type)},findByName:function(t){return e(this.currentForm).find("[name='"+this.escapeCssMeta(t)+"']")},getLength:function(t,n){switch(n.nodeName.toLowerCase()){case"select":return e("option:selected",n).length;case"input":if(this.checkable(n))return this.findByName(n.name).filter(":checked").length}return t.length},depend:function(e,t){return!this.dependTypes[typeof e]||this.dependTypes[typeof e](e,t)},dependTypes:{boolean:function(e){return e},string:function(t,n){return!!e(t,n.form).length},function:function(e,t){return e(t)}},optional:function(t){var n=this.elementValue(t);return!e.validator.methods.required.call(this,n,t)&&"dependency-mismatch"},startRequest:function(t){this.pending[t.name]||(this.pendingRequest++,e(t).addClass(this.settings.pendingClass),this.pending[t.name]=!0)},stopRequest:function(t,n){this.pendingRequest--,this.pendingRequest<0&&(this.pendingRequest=0),delete this.pending[t.name],e(t).removeClass(this.settings.pendingClass),n&&0===this.pendingRequest&&this.formSubmitted&&this.form()?(e(this.currentForm).submit(),this.formSubmitted=!1):!n&&0===this.pendingRequest&&this.formSubmitted&&(e(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form",[this]),this.formSubmitted=!1)},previousValue:function(t,n){return e.data(t,"previousValue")||e.data(t,"previousValue",{old:null,valid:!0,message:this.defaultMessage(t,{method:n})})},destroy:function(){this.resetForm(),e(this.currentForm).off(".validate").removeData("validator").find(".validate-equalTo-blur").off(".validate-equalTo").removeClass("validate-equalTo-blur")}},classRuleSettings:{required:{required:!0},email:{email:!0},url:{url:!0},date:{date:!0},dateISO:{dateISO:!0},number:{number:!0},digits:{digits:!0},creditcard:{creditcard:!0}},addClassRules:function(t,n){t.constructor===String?this.classRuleSettings[t]=n:e.extend(this.classRuleSettings,t)},classRules:function(t){var n={},i=e(t).attr("class");return i&&e.each(i.split(" "),function(){this in e.validator.classRuleSettings&&e.extend(n,e.validator.classRuleSettings[this])}),n},normalizeAttributeRule:function(e,t,n,i){/min|max|step/.test(n)&&(null===t||/number|range|text/.test(t))&&(i=Number(i),isNaN(i)&&(i=void 0)),i||0===i?e[n]=i:t===n&&"range"!==t&&(e[n]=!0)},attributeRules:function(t){var n,i,r={},o=e(t),s=t.getAttribute("type");for(n in e.validator.methods)"required"===n?(i=t.getAttribute(n),""===i&&(i=!0),i=!!i):i=o.attr(n),this.normalizeAttributeRule(r,s,n,i);return r.maxlength&&/-1|2147483647|524288/.test(r.maxlength)&&delete r.maxlength,r},dataRules:function(t){var n,i,r={},o=e(t),s=t.getAttribute("type");for(n in e.validator.methods)i=o.data("rule"+n.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+n.substring(1).toLowerCase()),this.normalizeAttributeRule(r,s,n,i);return r},staticRules:function(t){var n={},i=e.data(t.form,"validator");return i.settings.rules&&(n=e.validator.normalizeRule(i.settings.rules[t.name])||{}),n},normalizeRules:function(t,n){return e.each(t,function(i,r){if(r===!1)return void delete t[i];if(r.param||r.depends){var o=!0;switch(typeof r.depends){case"string":o=!!e(r.depends,n.form).length;break;case"function":o=r.depends.call(n,n)}o?t[i]=void 0===r.param||r.param:(e.data(n.form,"validator").resetElements(e(n)),delete t[i])}}),e.each(t,function(i,r){t[i]=e.isFunction(r)&&"normalizer"!==i?r(n):r}),e.each(["minlength","maxlength"],function(){t[this]&&(t[this]=Number(t[this]))}),e.each(["rangelength","range"],function(){var n;t[this]&&(e.isArray(t[this])?t[this]=[Number(t[this][0]),Number(t[this][1])]:"string"==typeof t[this]&&(n=t[this].replace(/[\[\]]/g,"").split(/[\s,]+/),t[this]=[Number(n[0]),Number(n[1])]))}),e.validator.autoCreateRanges&&(null!=t.min&&null!=t.max&&(t.range=[t.min,t.max],delete t.min,delete t.max),null!=t.minlength&&null!=t.maxlength&&(t.rangelength=[t.minlength,t.maxlength],delete t.minlength,delete t.maxlength)),t},normalizeRule:function(t){if("string"==typeof t){var n={};e.each(t.split(/\s/),function(){n[this]=!0}),t=n}return t},addMethod:function(t,n,i){e.validator.methods[t]=n,e.validator.messages[t]=void 0!==i?i:e.validator.messages[t],n.length<3&&e.validator.addClassRules(t,e.validator.normalizeRule(t))},methods:{required:function(t,n,i){if(!this.depend(i,n))return"dependency-mismatch";if("select"===n.nodeName.toLowerCase()){var r=e(n).val();return r&&r.length>0}return this.checkable(n)?this.getLength(t,n)>0:t.length>0},email:function(e,t){return this.optional(t)||/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(e)},url:function(e,t){return this.optional(t)||/^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})).?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[\/?#]\S*)?$/i.test(e)},date:function(e,t){return this.optional(t)||!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(e).toString())},dateISO:function(e,t){return this.optional(t)||/^\d{4}[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/.test(e)},number:function(e,t){return this.optional(t)||/^(?:-?\d+|-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(e)},digits:function(e,t){return this.optional(t)||/^\d+$/.test(e)},minlength:function(t,n,i){var r=e.isArray(t)?t.length:this.getLength(t,n);return this.optional(n)||r>=i},maxlength:function(t,n,i){var r=e.isArray(t)?t.length:this.getLength(t,n);return this.optional(n)||r<=i},rangelength:function(t,n,i){var r=e.isArray(t)?t.length:this.getLength(t,n);return this.optional(n)||r>=i[0]&&r<=i[1]},min:function(e,t,n){return this.optional(t)||e>=n},max:function(e,t,n){return this.optional(t)||e<=n},range:function(e,t,n){return this.optional(t)||e>=n[0]&&e<=n[1]},step:function(t,n,i){var r=e(n).attr("type"),o="Step attribute on input type "+r+" is not supported.",s=["text","number","range"],a=new RegExp("\\b"+r+"\\b"),l=r&&!a.test(s.join());if(l)throw new Error(o);return this.optional(n)||t%i===0},equalTo:function(t,n,i){var r=e(i);return this.settings.onfocusout&&r.not(".validate-equalTo-blur").length&&r.addClass("validate-equalTo-blur").on("blur.validate-equalTo",function(){e(n).valid()}),t===r.val()},remote:function(t,n,i,r){if(this.optional(n))return"dependency-mismatch";r="string"==typeof r&&r||"remote";var o,s,a,l=this.previousValue(n,r);return this.settings.messages[n.name]||(this.settings.messages[n.name]={}),l.originalMessage=l.originalMessage||this.settings.messages[n.name][r],this.settings.messages[n.name][r]=l.message,i="string"==typeof i&&{url:i}||i,a=e.param(e.extend({data:t},i.data)),l.old===a?l.valid:(l.old=a,o=this,this.startRequest(n),s={},s[n.name]=t,e.ajax(e.extend(!0,{mode:"abort",port:"validate"+n.name,dataType:"json",data:s,context:o.currentForm,success:function(e){var i,s,a,u=e===!0||"true"===e;o.settings.messages[n.name][r]=l.originalMessage,u?(a=o.formSubmitted,o.resetInternals(),o.toHide=o.errorsFor(n),o.formSubmitted=a,o.successList.push(n),o.invalid[n.name]=!1,o.showErrors()):(i={},s=e||o.defaultMessage(n,{method:r,parameters:t}),i[n.name]=l.message=s,o.invalid[n.name]=!0,o.showErrors(i)),l.valid=u,o.stopRequest(n,u)}},i)),"pending")}}});var t,n={};e.ajaxPrefilter?e.ajaxPrefilter(function(e,t,i){var r=e.port;"abort"===e.mode&&(n[r]&&n[r].abort(),n[r]=i)}):(t=e.ajax,e.ajax=function(i){var r=("mode"in i?i:e.ajaxSettings).mode,o=("port"in i?i:e.ajaxSettings).port;return"abort"===r?
```

My function where I USE validate():

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Validate the first registration form
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$("#register-step-one").validate({
    errorClass:'error',
    validClass:'success',
    errorElement:'span',
  onkeyup: false,
  rules: {
    first_name: { required: true },
    last_name: { required: true },
    email: { required: true, email: true },
    phone: { required: true },
    company: { required: true },
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
  },
});
```

Comment: Explain exactly what you mean when you say `.validate()` *"does not work"*.  Are you getting any JavaScript console errors?  Does it work when you don't use Gulp?

Comment: No console errors at all. When i use the exact same files and concat them with codekit it works fine.

Comment: This makes no sense.  If something went wrong with how the plugin was included, then you'd certainly get a console error when trying to call the `.validate()` method.

Comment: You would think so. I have 15 years of web development experience, and i'm stumped. Tried to figure it out for 6 hours today. I've given up on gulp and went back to codekit.

Answer (score 0):

Just a long shot, but try removing the unnecessary commas after the lines:

```
company: { required: true },
```

and

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
  form.submit();
},
```

I know some linters will complain about those.